# Allow search on Account without Read access (Private OWD)

Tags: sharing, duplicate-management, search, owd

So I've come across a requirement which require us to set the Account OWD to private, but users still need to be able to search for an account so that they know if it exists in the org or not. Kind of like how the duplicate rule works where you cannot actually see the account which is the duplicate, but you know that it's there.

Any ideas of how I could achieve this (if possible)?

I've been thinking about having to build some custom search with LWC/APEX but it would be nice to avoid that and evaluate other options :)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried by creating the Sharing rule to provide the Read access on the user to whom you would allow the Read access.

Comment: Unfortunetly this would not work for this case. The access needs to be private for all users, but they still need to be able to do a check to see if an account already exists - Without actually having access to it, or seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your stakeholder that the "Search" requirement is not possible on Salesforce standard functionality yet.

By Default the [Standard Account Duplicate Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_standard_account_rule.htm&type=5)  & Matching Rule should prompt users on **create** anyway if there exist a duplicate Account *e.g if Account Name & Phone is the same*

OR you can just create your own custom Account Matching Rule criteria

If these suggestions don't work with your stakeholders ,the last option is to upvote this idea that was reported 13 years ago https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BppV
to allow this requirement and hope it gets [Prioritized by Salesforce for next release](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/prioritization)

Comment: I agree with this assessment. If users need to _know the names of Accounts so that they know they exist_ then it sounds like at a minimum, users need Read access to the Account object, the sharing needs to be Public Read, and then - to limit the amount of detail a user can see on the Account - set field level security to the bare-minimum, which is only the Name field. I would bet that users may need even slightly more fields than the Name, such as the address to account for a situation like "Acme Co." USA and "Acme Co." UK, for example.